# C++ templates: why is not the specialized function called?

Tags: c++, templates

The template function exists as a general and a specialized case:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// General case
template<typename X> void whichOneIsLarger(X a, X b) {
    (a > b) ? cout << "x [" << a << "] is larger than y [" << b << "]" : cout << "y [" << b << "] is larger than x [" << a << "]" << endl;
}

// Specialization
template<> void whichOneIsLarger<string>(string a, string b) {
    (a.size() > b.size()) ? cout << "x [" << a << "] is longer than y [" << b << "]" : cout << "y [" << b << "] is longer than x [" << a << "]" << endl;
}
```

When calling it using strings, I expected both calls to use the specialization, why is that not the case?

```
int main()
{
    string hallo = "hallo"; string world = "world";

    whichOneIsLarger(hallo, world);         // <-- Calls specialization
    whichOneIsLarger("hallo", "world");     // <-- Calls general case
}
```

Comment: `"hallo"`is not a std::string

Comment: In general you should avoid "function specializations". Read this article: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `"hallo"` and `"world"` are not `std::string`s, but [c-style string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (with type `const char[6]` and could decay to `const char*`).

You can pass `std::string` explicitly,

```
whichOneIsLarger(std::string("hallo"), std::string("world"));
```

Or use [`std::string` literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
whichOneIsLarger("hallo"s, "world"s);
```

If you want to specify with c-style string literals, you can

```
template<> void whichOneIsLarger<const char*>(const char* a, const char* b)
```

Note that you have to provide *special* implementation for `const char*`.

Comment: How to specialize for the C-String? Trying `template<> void whichOneIsLarger<char*>(char* a, char* b)` but its not catching.

Comment: `const char *` ... the `const` is needed

Comment: This is a case for `std::string_view`.